# Leading zero in calculator swift2

Tags: ios, swift2, leading-zero

I've got a problem with leading zero in my simple app (Calculator). On start Zero is printed on label, but when I tap button for example "1" I see "01". It doesn't look good, so I would to change it. My code is below. Can somebody help me in it?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var previousValue:Int?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typicala       nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//display
@IBOutlet weak var displayLabel: UILabel!

// buttons
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

   let numb = (sender as! UIButton).tag

    displayLabel.text = "\(displayLabel.text!)\(numb)"

}
//plus    
@IBAction func plusPress(sender: AnyObject) {
    previousValue = Int(displayLabel.text!)
    displayLabel.text = "+"

}
//minus    
@IBAction func minusPress(sender: AnyObject) {
    previousValue = Int(displayLabel.text!)
    displayLabel.text = "-"
}

// count
@IBAction func count(sender: AnyObject) {
    let result = previousValue! + Int(displayLabel.text!)!
    displayLabel.text = "\(result)"

}


@IBAction func clear(sender: AnyObject) {
    displayLabel.text=""
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the contents of `displayLabel.text` first.  If it is `0`, then just set `displayLabel.text` to the number that was pressed.  Also, if you declare `sender` in `buttonPressed` to be a `UIButton`, then you don't have to cast it:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let numb = sender.tag

    if displayLabel.text == "0" {
        displayLabel.text = "\(numb)"
    }
    else {
        displayLabel.text = "\(displayLabel.text!)\(numb)"
    }
}
```